# Tools for Managing Personal Font Libraries

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, tools

I have a ton of licensed fonts from various foundries (1,000+).

Is there a tool out there similar to Typekit that would enable me to host/organize my personal font library on the cloud AND keep them continuously synched across my devices and design programs such as Sketch, Adobe CC, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

1. [Fontbase](https://fontba.se/) is free and beautifuly designed. It's updated quite frequently too.
2. [NexusFont](http://www.xiles.net/) is also free and is one of the most widely used ones.
3. [Suitcase Fusion](http://www.extensis.com/font-management/suitcase-fusion/) is an industry standard but it's quite pricey. However it has excellent syncing between applications.

---

There are many more options but these are in my opinion the top 3.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [FontAgent](https://www.insidersoftware.com/font-managers/compare-fontagent-editions/) since the early 2000s.

Before that I Use the Adobe Type Manager (which is dead now). I've tried Suitcase and FontExplorer and always found them more troublesome than helpful. That's just my opinion/experience though.